# Float vertical postioning

Tags: css, css-float

I have just started learning HTMl and CSS. I am having a hard time understanding how floats work. The book that I am learning from says:

> the float property moves an element as far as possible to the left or right, allowing the following content to wrap around it.

I have an image inside a paragraph and I am using float to move the image around but I am not very sure which content wraps and how far to the top/bottom of the containing element does the image move to.

This is the paragraph without float applied with "no following  content" after the image. The base of the image is aligned with base of the text line:

```
     <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum<img src="icon.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
     </p>
```

If I float the image to the left only the last four words seems to be wrapping around the image. I have tried putting the image in other positions in the paragraph and I unable to figure:

a) How far up or down does the image move to when floated?
b) Which text gets wrapped around the image (doesn't seem to be only the following content as in the book).

Do I need to be bothered about this?